# HTTPS proxies not working with Python's requests module

Tags: python, https, python-requests

I'm pretty new to Python and I've been using their requests module as a substitute for PHP's cURL library. My code is as follows

```
import requests
import json
import os
import urllib
import math
import sys

def main() :    
   url = 'https://api.com'

   headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
              'User-Agent': '(iPhone; iOS 7.0.4; Scale/2.00)'}

   d = {'token': "12345"}

   proxies = {
      "https": "https://27.254.52.99:8080",
   }

   post = json.dumps(d);
   r = requests.post(url, data=post, headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
   print r.json

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

However, I'm greeted with the following error:

```
File "test.py", line 42, in test
r = requests.post(url, data=post, headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests-2.2.1-py2.7.egg/requests/api.py", line 88, in post
return request('post', url, data=data, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests-2.2.1-py2.7.egg/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests-2.2.1-py2.7.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 383, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests-2.2.1-py2.7.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 486, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests-2.2.1-py2.7.egg/requests/adapters.py", line 381, in send
raise ProxyError(e)
ProxyError: Cannot connect to proxy. Socket error: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer.
```

Comment: Can't find anything odd about the code. And the error seems to indicate there is a connection issue. Does curl or wget work from the same machine?

Comment: Here is also a nice tool to play with proxies. http://www.charlesproxy.com/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Edit June 2019: This reply is not relevant anymore. Issue(s) are fixed.**

**Edit 2**: "note that even for https proxy, the proxy address' scheme is http, it's because the client and proxy server initiate the tunnelling(the CONNECT method) in plain http. However, that's may not be true 3 years ago." - From the comments

HTTPS is 'bugged' in requests. I don't know the specifics but you can find a few other topics on this website concerning the issue. Also a Github issue is still active [here](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/50). I'm suspecting you're having the problems mentioned there. If I am totally wrong, someone correct me.

To verify:

```
$~ curl --proxy https://27.254.52.99:8080 icanhazip.com
27.254.52.99
```

Works, but then in Python:

```
>>> proxies={'https': 'https://27.254.52.99:8080'}
>>> r = requests.get('http://icanhazip.com', headers={'User-Agent': 'Bla'}, proxies=proxies)
print r.content
<my ipv6 address comes up>
```

As you can see, my address comes up which means the proxy did nothing.

I don't understand why you are receiving a stacktrace. Maybe because your API is on HTTPS as well (?). Or maybe your API is just... down.

Anyway, the proxy does work in requests if its over HTTP.

```
>>> proxies={'http': 'http://27.254.52.99:8080'}
>>> r = requests.head('http://icanhazip.com', headers={'User-Agent': 'Bla'}, proxies=proxies)
print r.content
27.254.52.99
```

Comment: @Lance: Any luck yet?

Comment: Sorry for he delay. Yes, this worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: You guys all misunderstood what a https proxy is. the correct form should be {'https': 'http://example.com:3128'}, note the http part

Comment: @ospider how is that different from my 1st example? besides, this answer was based on a bug `requests` was having, 3 years ago.

Comment: note that even for https proxy, the proxy address' scheme is http, it's because the client and proxy server initiate the tunnelling(the CONNECT method) in plain http. However, that's may not be true 3 years ago.

Comment: Instead of "http", use "http://"

Comment: It worked for me when I switched on the UA

Comment: @falselight do you mean, like proxies={"http:\\": "http:\\27.254.52.99:8080","https:\\": "http:\\27.254.52.99:8080"}  (sorry had to replace // with \\ to be shown here) ?