# Python "Xbox username checker" program using requests module and proxies hangs without error

Tags: python, python-requests, proxies

I am building a program that is checking Xbox usernames from a text file, and whenever I attempt to use it it will hang for about 20 seconds and stop with no error. I am hosting this program on Replit for now.
My code is:

```
import requests
import pyfiglet
from colorama import Fore
import time
from getkey import getkey
proxies = {
  "http": "http://43.155.59.126:3128",
  "http": "http://88.198.24.108:3128",
  "http": "http://178.47.141.85:2580",
}
def turbo():
  url = 'https://xboxgamertag.com/search/'
  filename = input('File name?\n')
  with open(filename) as f:
      line = f.readline()
      while line:
          line = f.readline()
          req = requests.get(url + line, proxies=proxies)
          if req == '200':
            print(Fore.RED + "[AVAILABLE] " + line)
          elif req == '404':
            print(Fore.GREEN + "[AVAILABLE] " + line)
def menu():
  menu = pyfiglet.figlet_format("Xbox Turbo") 
  print(menu)
  time.sleep(0.5)
  print(Fore.GREEN + "made by ooaz#0001")
  time.sleep(0.5)
  print(Fore.WHITE + "[1] Xbox Turbo")
  key = getkey()
  if key == '1':
    turbo()
menu()
```

The proxies are NOT confirmed working.

Comment: `f.readline()` will return lines with newline chars `\n` at the end, does stripping these off with `line = f.readline().strip()` work?

Comment: Added it like this:       while line:
          line = f.readline()
          line = line.strip() and it didnt work

Comment: Wait I see you edited it let me try that

Comment: @IainShelvington error: attributerror: builtin_function_or_method object has no attribute strip

Comment: @IainShelvington Am I supposed to put it outside or inside the while? I put it inside

Comment: I think you may not be chaining the methods correctly. You should also check the status of the response using `req.status_code` like: `if req.status_code == 200:`

Comment: reponse.get returns a Response object.  You compare it to the strings '200' and '404', and that will almost certainly be False.  If so, your program won't produce any output.  I think you want to compare req.status_code with integer values 200 and 404.

Comment: Trying this, thanks

Comment: Got past the error with the strip and I tried the req.status_code and it still isn't loading. I think you should check the Replit I made to see further errors: https://replit.com/@s1ushy/FondHightechJavascript#main.py:30

Comment: @vey compare the status_code to an int not a string: `if req.status_code == 200:`

Comment: tried that with int(200): it didn't work

Comment: @vey can you add another condition/print for `if req.status_code == 403:`? You might just be getting permission denied everytime

Comment: That's what it was, thanks :)

Comment: Now I have to find another proxy lmao

Answer (score 1):

I think you need replace your proxies by:

```
proxies = {
  "http": "http://43.155.59.126:3128",
  "https": "http://43.155.59.126:3128"
}
```

Choose one, but `proxies` is a dictionary, with the protocol and the proxie

More information https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies

Comment: Still no, check my Replit: https://replit.com/@s1ushy/FondHightechJavascript#main.py:30

Comment: Try to implement a minimal test, just doing the request. There are other questions about this issue on SO too, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058127/https-proxies-not-working-with-pythons-requests-module

Answer (score 1):

Most, if not all, large sites detect bots. Sometimes by naively inspecting your sent user agent and, sometimes, by more sophisticated means such as probing your "browser" for capabilities such as playing sound or having a window resolution.
Looks like this is the case:

```py
>>> import requests
>>> result = requests.get('https://xboxgamertag.com/search/foo')
>>> result
<Response [403]>
>>> result.reason
'Forbidden'
```

Adding proxies

```py
>>> proxies = {
...   "https": "http://43.155.59.126:3128",
...   "http": "http://88.198.24.108:3128",
...   "http": "http://178.47.141.85:2580",
... }
>>> result = requests.get('https://xboxgamertag.com/search/foo', proxies=proxies)
>>> result
<Response [403]>
>>> result.reason
'Forbidden'
```

Comment: I understand this and I am still playing with proxies that I am trying to use for this, just trying to get the program up before I edit the proxy chain

Comment: That's fair but the HTTP response and reason remain the same. Most likely falling into the same detection category. But, regardless, replit fails because of a script execution timeout. The proxies take a very long time to respond (expected)

Comment: @vey if the site is especially stubborn, you can try Selenium. It is more complex than `requests` and requires reading+patience. But, it uses a browser "driver" to talk HTTP, increasing your chances. Some _very_ stubborn sites detect these automation frameworks using said driver's special JS libraries. To which you also have methods of treating. And the rabbit hole goes on.